# Querying Table Formatting in ChatGPT: How to Achieve Microsoft Word-Like Presentation?

Tags: chatgpt

In my interactions with ChatGPT, I encountered a challenge in displaying tables in a format similar to Microsoft Word's ordinary table format. I've successfully generated a table in the Microsoft Word table format using ChatGPT. However, when I attempt to replicate the same table without block code formatting, the result appears as block code.

**Problem Illustration:**

1. **Microsoft Word-Like Format (Desired):**
   [image]
2. **Block Code Format (Undesired):**
   [image]

**Question:**
How can I instruct ChatGPT to generate tables without block code formatting, resembling the Microsoft Word table format? I want to maintain the visual clarity and structure akin to a table created in Microsoft Word.